# PostgreSQL (SQL) IF ELSE THEN need syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create the following function that checks if something exists. It should return true or false. THen i created a trigger to execute the function. Does not work at all /syntax errors everywhere. Help please!

```
CREATE FUNCTION checkForGPU() RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $approved$
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (
            SELECT C.ID
            FROM Components C, ComputerComponents CC, ComponentType T, Computer PC
            WHERE CC.ComputerID = C.ID  
            AND CC.ComputerID = PC.ID
            AND C.Type = T.ID
            AND T.Name = 'GPU')
        THEN 
            RETURN TRUE
        ELSE THEN
        RETURN FALSE

    END;    
    $approved$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER checkGPU
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ComputerComponents
EXECUTE PROCEDURE checkForGPU();
```

Comment: `ELSE THEN` is not correct.

Comment: How do i write the else statement correctly then?

Comment: Right syntax you could see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html). Section 39.6.2.2.

Comment: @kvorobiev i've read that. Can't find it. How to return a TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function could be rewrited much simpler, without IF-THEN-ELSE statement

```
CREATE FUNCTION checkForGPU() RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $approved$
    BEGIN
        RETURN EXISTS(
            SELECT C.ID
            FROM Components AS C, ComputerComponents AS CC, ComponentType AS T, Computer AS PC
            WHERE CC.ComputerID = C.ID  
            AND CC.ComputerID = PC.ID
            AND C.Type = T.ID
            AND T.Name = 'GPU'
        );
    END;    
    $approved$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. However, there is a syntax error near "END": https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7647549/Udklip.PNG

Comment: And I forget ; after the EXISTS(...). Please, try one more time.